# Facing error while establishing Sq-lite connection in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

In WP app, i am trying to make a connection with `existing` Sqlite database but failing with the Sqlite exception `"near ")": syntax error"`. I have included another C++ project in the solution.

```
string dbPath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "QuranApp2.db");
                using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath))
                {
                    db.RunInTransaction(() =>
                    {
                        db.Insert(new Book() { Book_ID = 5, BookDescription = "Tucker" });
                    });
                }
```

Note that `QuranApp2.db` is in `Assets` folder.
[image]

Comment: Which statement fails?

Comment: works fine if leave i leave the using block empty. otherwise shows error on db.RunInTransaction statement. i have replace this statement with some othr. then it gives error that newly created statement. @CL.